# Why is my custom date filter (angular) returning gobbledy-gook?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The markup (Jade)

```
.col-md-9
       | {{client.person.date_of_birth | date:'standardDate'}}
```

The filter (angular)

```
  .filter('standardDate', function($filter){
      var dateFilter = $filter('date');
      return function(date) {
        return dateFilter(date, 'MM dd yyyy');
      }
  })
```

The filtered date it returns:

```
0nStAMn16AMr16DAMte
```

When I use one of angular's preset date formatters (e.g. 'shortdate'), this works, suggesting the date param is not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to pass in the `date` filter, as your `standardDate` filter already brings in the `$filter` service and returns the filtered date all on its own.

So, your markup should look like this:

```
.col-md-9
       | {{client.person.date_of_birth | standardDate }}
```

Comment: Wow, great answer, Bryce!